# How to create ionic-angular starter application with latest angular and ionic version?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, responsive-design, hybrid-mobile-app, ionic5

I have created a starter application of ionic angular by using below command

ionic start helloWorld blank --type=ionic-angular

I have observed that in package.json I am having all older version (PFA)

[image]

How to upgrade these with all the latest versions? (angular-9 and ionic-5)

Am I using the old "--type=ionic-angular" in the creation command?

Can someone pls help me?

Answer (score 0):

This flag is the culprit `--type=ionic-angular`.

This flag tells ionic cli to install the `ionic-angular` package which is based on Angular 5.

`ionic start helloWorld blank` is enough to create an Ionic project with latest versions of Ionic and Angular.

Comment: ionic -v
6.10.1
I am having this version now.
Ionic documentation having version till 5.2 only I am surprised why it's giving me 6.10.1

Comment: @vinod Ionic cli package is different from the ionic core packages. Ionic core's latest version is 5.2.0 but the cli's version is 6.10.1

Comment: Harish, I agree with you Thank you!

I am having below versions
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI          : 6.10.1 
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.10
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.4

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v12.16.3 
   npm    : 6.14.4
   OS     : Linux 4.4

Comment: Above starter application, I have created by using --type=ionic-angular
is it the reason I am getting old version?

Comment: Oh. My bad. It looks like `--type=ionic-angular` is the culprit. I just created a project without that flag and I got the latest versions of Ionic and Angular.

Comment: It's K Np!

I think this was the older way and we are not following it from ionic 4.
If we create an application with just "ionic start myapp"  then it will give you all new versions.